# How to autopopulate 2 lookups at record creation?

Tags: custom-object, lookup, account, contact

In Classic, when we created custom object records from related Contacts or Accounts, it would automatically fill in that Account (from Account record),  or Account and Contact (from Contact record). In Lightning, this does not happen. Is there a way that it needs to be set up, or do I need to look into creating a trigger to do so ahead of time?

Comment: Are you using custom buttons to create records?

Comment: @sanket I did find one button that may be the culprit.

https://na6.salesforce.com/a06/e?CF00N80000002Ysw6={!Contact.Name} 
&CF00N80000002Ysw5={!Account.Name} 
&CF00N80000002Ysw5_lkid={!Account.Id} 
&CF00N80000002Ysw6_lkid={!Contact.Id} 
&retURL=%2F0038000000W2dyE

1, this doesn't look right to me.
2, why would it react differently based on where it was being used?

Answer (score 2):

URL Hacks are back and in Lightning with Spring ’20, But there have a different base URL as you can see in the below example of a custom button URL

```
/lightning/o/Contact/new?defaultFieldValues=
OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId}, AccountId={!Account.Id},
MailingStreet={!Account.ShippingStreet},
MailingCity={!Account.ShippingCity}
```

- This doesn’t work on mobile. Hopefully, we’ll see this updated in the future.

Reference: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm

Answer (score 0):

The custom button is doing URL hacking , hence auto populating in classic. However, hacking doesn't work in lightning. So, you would have to achieve this in lightning using some different approach like making aura component than using URL hacking.